# Traverse every node of a tree to a given depth

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have a binary tree exactly like a Family Tree. with what I call the "Lead Child" as the root, with both parents below, then 4 grandparents below that, then 8 grandparents below that. So basically a binary tree of depth 4 generations.

I want to be able to traverse every node and extract the information (i.e the name) of each node and store it in an array - the array will of course have 15 elements for 4 generations (1+2+4+8). I'm struggling to do this recursively. All of the examples I have found on the net which use the usual methods (pre-order, in-order, post-order) simply stop when reaching an empty node, but that is NOT what I want to do: I want every node to be visited but stop when all nodes have been visited of 4 generations (or any given number of generations. The crucial thing is to stop at precisely 4 generations, even if some of the nodes are empty or Null. Can anyone provide a solution please? It's been taxing my head for ages. Thanks for reading

Comment: Are you looking for the answer in some specific language ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Basic for Applications in MS Access (where my data is stored but I guess any similar pseudocode that resembles it would be fine

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation in MIU (made it up):

```
 traverse(node):
     traverse_(node, 0)

 traverse_(node, i):
     if i >= 4:
         return

     # Do stuff here.

     traverese_(node.left, i + 1)
     traverese_(node.right, i + 1)
```

Now you just need to call `traverse` on the root node.

Comment: This will call `traverse_` for  5 generations (i=0,1,2,3,4).  Of course, you don't specify when anything gets done (i.e. adding to the array), so that might be OK.

Comment: Thanks, corrected. (Of course, in standard MIU > means greater or equal, and a blank line has side effects, but I realize not everyone is familiar with this language. :-) )

Comment: I've tried your solution quickly and it almost works - there's a slight error somewhere in that it's visiting a couple of the nodes twice for some reason - I'll have to step through it manually and see where the problem is, but thanks, that's put me on the right path. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive depth-first search will indeed stop when it reaches a leaf node, that is, a node that doesn't have any children (note that what you might call "parents" in a family tree are actually called "children" from a graph-theoretical perspective). However, since it's a recursive algorithm, "stopping" simply means that the algorithm will return to the node from which it came, and try the other children of that node. So the algorithm as a whole doesn't stop. A standard DFS, whether it's prefix, infix, or postfix, will visit the entire tree. The only thing you need to do is to add an extra parameter to your recursive function: one that tracks the current depth.

Comment: That the bit that's got me stumpedI'm afraid!

Comment: See Ami Tavory's answer - `i` is the current recursion depth, and in each recursive call, you increment `i` by 1.